# VS Code is showing red curly lines for MySql code even if my code is correct and running fine

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-code, intellisense, rdbms

See the attached screenshot and I've also attached the code:

```
CREATE TABLE student_info(
    student_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    class VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'Final Year Student',
    PRIMARY KEY(student_id)
);

DESCRIBE student_info;
```

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FASqY.png)

Comment: I'd guess it checks for the SQL Sever dialect. Apparently there are extensions for MySQL though: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakebathman.mysql-syntax

Comment: Nope it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Look at the very bottom of your screenshot, in the blue bar. It states it's detecting it as "MSSQL".